# Operations on computable functions

Tags: functions, computability

Given a computable function $f\colon D \rightarrow D$, can I make the following operations and still end up with a computable function? Or in other words: are the following operations computable?

- Scaling, i.e. for a rational number $r$, is $r\cdot f$ still computable? Multiplication here is meant in a pointwise matter.
- Taking the minimum/maximum between $f_1$ and $f_2$ (again pointwise)
- Additivity, i.e. is $f_1 + f_2$ (pointwise addition) computable?

I am fairly certain that these claims are true, but am not sure how to show it. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What is $D$? Many people define computability for functions from natural numbers to natural numbers. Some other people define it for functions from strings to strings. In such contexts, pointwise multiplication by a rational number $r$ doesn't make sense.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Let's say D are the rational numbers